# get set to apex:selectOption

Tags: visualforce, controller, selectlist

I am trying to set a value from my controller to my apex:selectOption value. I have created a get set method and the value in the get set have been changed but no change at all in apex:selectOption.

My code:

```
      <apex:selectList id="chooseStartTime" value="{!startTime_FromVf}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="01:00  AM" itemLabel="01:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="01:30  AM" itemLabel="01:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="02:00  AM" itemLabel="02:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="02:30  AM" itemLabel="02:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="03:00  AM" itemLabel="03:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="03:30  AM" itemLabel="03:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="04:00  AM" itemLabel="04:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="04:30  AM" itemLabel="04:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="05:00  AM" itemLabel="05:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="05:30  AM" itemLabel="05:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="06:00  AM" itemLabel="06:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="06:30  AM" itemLabel="06:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="07:00  AM" itemLabel="07:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="07:30  AM" itemLabel="07:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="08:00  AM" itemLabel="08:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="08:30  AM" itemLabel="08:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="09:00  AM" itemLabel="09:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="09:30  AM" itemLabel="09:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:00  AM" itemLabel="10:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="10:30  AM" itemLabel="10:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:00  AM" itemLabel="11:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="11:30  AM" itemLabel="11:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="12:00  AM" itemLabel="12:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="12:30  AM" itemLabel="12:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="13:00  AM" itemLabel="13:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="13:30  AM" itemLabel="13:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="14:00  AM" itemLabel="14:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="14:30  AM" itemLabel="14:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="15:00  AM" itemLabel="15:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="15:30  AM" itemLabel="15:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="16:00  AM" itemLabel="16:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="16:30  AM" itemLabel="16:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="17:00  AM" itemLabel="17:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="17:30  AM" itemLabel="17:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="18:00  AM" itemLabel="18:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="18:30  AM" itemLabel="18:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="19:00  AM" itemLabel="19:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="19:30  AM" itemLabel="19:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="20:00  AM" itemLabel="20:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="20:30  AM" itemLabel="20:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="21:00  AM" itemLabel="21:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="21:30  AM" itemLabel="21:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="22:00  AM" itemLabel="22:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="22:30  AM" itemLabel="22:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="23:00  AM" itemLabel="23:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="23:30  AM" itemLabel="23:30  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="24:00  AM" itemLabel="24:00  AM"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="24:30  AM" itemLabel="24:30  AM"/>
        </apex:selectList>
```

controller

```
public String getstartTime_FromVf() {
    system.debug('time_fromVF in get ' + time_fromVF);
    return time_fromVF;
}

public void setstartTime_FromVf(String time_fromVF) {
    system.debug('time_fromVF ' + time_fromVF);
    this.time_fromVF = time_fromVF;
}
```

I am calling this function in my controller

```
setstartTime_FromVf(time_fromVF);
```

But this do not works. Please help me to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you could try:
1) Make sure the value in your controller matches exactly the value in your picklist.  You have two spaces between the time and AM/PM

2) The colon (:) might be messing up the value in Visualforce.  To get around this, I would do one of two things.. if this VF page is using a standard controller, why not create a picklist on the field with those times and render it in visualforce with   If that's not the case, then think about generating those values in the controller as Select Options instead, as seen here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm